# Computed bit column that returns whether another column is null

Tags: sql-server-2005, null, calculated-columns, isnull

I try to have this computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
    ItemId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    SpecialItemId int NULL,
    --I tried this
    IsSpecialItem AS ISNULL(SpecialItemId, 0) > 0, 
    --I tried this
    IsSpecialItem AS SpecialItemId IS NOT NULL
    --Both don't work
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
    ItemId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    SpecialItemId int NULL,
    IsSpecialItem AS
        CAST(CASE ISNULL(SpecialItemId, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit)
)
```

Comment: This only works when the column being tested is numeric. If SpecialItemId is nvarchar and has a value then this causes an error. See my other answer

Answer (score 21):

[Mark Byer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854377/75500) causes an error with `nvarchar` columns, the following works regardless of whether column is `int` or `nvarchar`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
    ItemId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    SpecialItemId [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CAST(CASE WHEN SpecialItemId Is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit)
      AS IsSpecialItem 
)
```

Comment: Also works with `varbinary`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't have any native true boolean data type (in the sense that you could use a variable in place of a boolean expression, like `select * from Item where IsSpecialItem`). The only way you can represent it is with something like Mark suggests, using reserved values (in this case, your query would be `select * from Item where IsSpecialItem = 1`).